# On Substrate ink! How can I get Debug information?

Tags: substrate, rust-ink

1. I want to get Debug Information.
2. I implemented this code,but I can not get.
3. Please tell me how can I get Debug Infomation.

```
        #[ink(message)]
        fn set_test_data(&mut self, value: String) {
            ink_core::env::println(value);
            self.test_data.set(value);
        }
```

Comment: This `println` should show up in your console when you execute this function. Make sure that you are submitting this as a real transaction, not using the RPC.

Comment: thank you for your answer.

I am trying below, but Is this "real transaction"?

1.I execute substrate by the command "substrate --dev".And I upload & deploy this "Contract".

2.I call this function using "send a transaction" of "Call a Contract" menu on "Polkadot/Substrate Portal".

Comment: `ink_core::env::println(value);` is now `ink_env::env::println(value);`

Comment: ink_env::debug_println(value); actually

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those error messages are printed to the console. Please note that you need to supply the following command line arguments to your node in order to make this happen:

1. `--dev`: Use the dev chain spec. You should already be using that.
2. `-lruntime=debug`: Increase the log level for runtime generated messages.

Answer (score 0):

It's now in the ink_env crate:

`ink_env::debug_println!("{}", "Hello log");`

The FAQ entry on this is here:

https://paritytech.github.io/ink-docs/faq/#how-do-i-print-something-to-the-console-from-the-runtime